# How to mock PreferenceManager in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, android-preferences

I've written a class that is using `Context`, a third party library and `SharedPreferences` from `PreferenceManager`.

It's possible to mock `Context`, the third party library can be mocked using some mocking framework, but what to do with `PreferenceManager`?

I have two methods:

```
public void saveString(ThirdPartyObject obj) {
    SharedPreferences appPreferences = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(mContext.getString(
        R.string.preferences_string_name), obj.getString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

and corresponding, that loads preferences.

Comment: Is there any particular behaviour in `PreferenceManager` that you need to mock? Otherwise testing preference code works fine from an `AndroidTestCase`.

Comment: It's a shame that I can't accept a comment - but what you've written satisfies me.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't look like you actually want a mock instance of `PreferenceManager` (which is mostly used in a `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceActivity`).

You probably want either:

1. A mock `SharedPreferences`, in which case you can just mock `Context#getSharedPreferences` (which is called by `PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences` anyhow). You'll probably also have to make a mock `SharedPreferences.Editor` if preferences are edited, as above. You say you already know how to mock the context, so this should be fairly straightforward.
2. To use the actual preferences in the environment. This is easiest, and not necessarily a bad idea. Do make certain it's cleaned up properly so that your tests don't interfere with each other (or, depending on your test environment, aren't affected by manual use of the app).

If you really *do* want to mock `PreferenceManager` instance (like that you get in `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceActivity`), you can absolutely do so.

Since it's non-final, you can generate a mock `PreferenceManager` and `SharedPreferences` using Mockito (or another mocking library) as long as you have a way to provide it to your code wherever you would ordinarily get one (in non-test code, this normally comes from the `getPreferenceManager()`).

Comment: `Context#getSharedPreferences` requires you to pass a file name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use specialized context for shared preference. `RenamingDelegatingContext` delegates everything to a Context. When we access SharedPreference from a `Context`, we use `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`.

Here by extending `RenamingDelegatingContext` we override getSharedPreferences and pretend the name parameter with test `PREFIX`, So when test runs it will write to preference file which is different then main application.

```
public class SpecializedMockContext extends RenamingDelegatingContext {
    public static final String PREFIX = "test.";

    public SpecializedMockContext(Context context) {
        super(context, PREFIX);
    }

    @Override
    public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
        return super.getSharedPreferences(PREFIX + name, mode);
    }
}
```

Set this SpecialisedMockContext to your test Application context. `setContext(specialisedMockContext)` and `createApplication()`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer isn't getting any upvotes; I've added mine. It certainly documents what I've done in the past and has worked well for me. If you've got a limited stable of real devices, as most of us do, then not-polluting a working set of preferences is important for test code.

Comment: Where do you call `setContext(specialisedMockContext)`?